# SQL: Compare 2 tables with duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, compare, duplicates

I need to compare 2 tables to find a duplicate, but the fields allow duplicates.

```
For Example: 
Tbl1:
455
7991
7991

Tbl2: 
455
7991
7991
7991
```

I need to write a query that shows there is an extra 7991 in table 2. I tried a right join but it still finds the match so it doesn't work properly. If anyone could point me in the right direction i'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!!

Comment: It's your only value in the table , are the other values of the 7991 are different ?

Comment: This is for Microsoft Access. I tried the codes below but they didn't work out. I am not sure I understand your question greg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  t1.colname
FROM    ( SELECT    colname
                  , COUNT(colname) AS colCount
          FROM      tbl1
          GROUP BY  colname
        ) t1
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT   colname
                      , COUNT(colname) AS colCount
               FROM     tbl2
               GROUP BY colname
             ) t2 ON t1.colname = t2.colname
                     AND t1.colCount <> t2.colCount
```

Comment: +1 This looks to me like the correct approach for MS Access.  I edited the SQL because I don't think Access' db engine accepts JOIN as a synonym for INNER JOIN.  Change it if you intended something else.  If it doesn't work as written, I would move `t1.colCount <> t2.colCount` to a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports FULL OUTER JOIN (not MySQL) this will give you all the differences between the two tables:

```
SELECT
    T1.x,
    COALESCE(T1.cnt, 0) AS T1_count,
    COALESCE(T2.cnt, 0) AS T2_count
FROM
(
    SELECT x, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM Tbl1
    GROUP BY x
) T1
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
    SELECT x, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM Tbl2
    GROUP BY x
) T2
ON T1.x = T2.x
WHERE T1.cnt <> T2.cnt
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! i'll get on it now.